# reactjs with react-router doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get a simple reactjs SPA with nodejs running, but my Router won't work correctly.
I created a new App with create-react-app and added npm install react-router.
My package.json is

```
{
"name": "App",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"react": "^15.5.0",
"react-dom": "^15.5.0",
"react-router": "^4.0.0"
    },
"devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
}
```

I just put the react components in a different folder to src/compoents/
and my index.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This works as aspected. The App comes up and shows the hello world example from reactjs.
But when I replace the App with the Router

```
<Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path='/' component={ App }/>
</Router>
```

The App breaks. Even with IndexRoute, the App doesn't work.

Changing hasHistory to browserHistory or createMemoryHistory doesn't change anything.

Could you please give me a hint in the right direction, what I'm missing?

Comment: How does the app break? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: in the console I get a warning that the history is required TypeError: this.props.history is undefined Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router (at index.js:8)

Comment: You are initializing `react-router` in the pre version 4.0 manner, check [the docs for setting up `react-router` 4.0](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) or downgrade to an older version of the package

Comment: could you please give a short answer, so I can reward you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rob M. you are my hero!
Thank you!
That was exactly the point.

When I changed the version of *react-router* to 2.8. as you suggested, it worked just fine.

If I understood the docs correctly, its advised to use the *react-router-dom* instead with the higher level router

```
<BrowserRouter>
<HashRouter>
<MemoryRouter>
<NativeRouter>
<StaticRouter>
```

Did I got this correctly?